# Initializer provides no value for this binding element and the binding element has no default value

Tags: typescript

I have the typescript error above. Here is my line of code

```
const {params:{guid} = {}} = useRouteMatch('/navigate/poi/:guid') ?? {}
```

Basically I'm destructuring the url. Using params and all works, just typescript complains with the error above when I hover over `guid`. I read through the other questions related to this, but I could not figure it out so far. Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, you're setting `params` to `{}` which doesn't contain `guid` when destructured. You have to do it like this:

```
const {params:{guid} = {guid: /*Default Value*/}} = useRouteMatch('/navigate/poi/:guid') ?? {}
```

Replace `/*Default Value*/` with whatever you want `guid` to default to (e.g. `''` or `undefined`.)